# Creating XPS-file programmatically creates corrupted file

Tags: c#, .net, xps

I am having problems creating a XPS-file programmatically. The code below does generate a XPS-file but when I try to open it is somehow corrupted and won't open. The output file isn't empty and its size is about right for type document I am trying to create. Output can be downloaded at [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/613b9czbkmslcuo/test.xps?dl=0)

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var writer = File.OpenWrite("c:/temp/test.xps"))
        {
            using (var s = getXpsStream())
            {
                s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                s.CopyTo(writer);
            }
        }
    }
    static Stream getXpsStream()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var package = Package.Open(stream, FileMode.Create);
        var xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Normal);
        var xpsWriter = xpsDoc.AddFixedDocumentSequence();
        string tempPath = "c:/temp/Document";
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            var docWriter = xpsWriter.AddFixedDocument();
            var pageWriter = docWriter.AddFixedPage();
            var image = pageWriter.AddImage(XpsImageType.JpegImageType);

            using (Stream imageStream = image.GetStream())
            {
                string filename = tempPath + i;
                using (var istream = File.OpenRead(filename + ".png"))
                {
                    istream.CopyTo(imageStream);
                }
            }
        }
        xpsDoc.Close();
        return stream;
    }
```

Comment: Is the file size greater than 0? I'm guessing your program ends before the buffer is written to the disc.

Comment: The output file isn't empty.

Comment: An XPS file is just a ZIP file structured with XML files, fonts, and other resources. If you rename it to .ZIP can you view or extract the contents correctly? That may help troubleshooting where the issue may be.

Comment: The *using* statement looks very unhealthy.  Follow the [code example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.xps.packaging.ixpsfixedpagewriter.addimage?view=netframework-4.8), note the Commit() calls and that the image/stream doesn't get disposed.